# Django : Forbidden CSRF cookie not set.)

Tags: django, cookies, csrf

I''m using Django with pyJWT to generate JWT for a simple login. Although it previously worked well now I'm getting **Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)** error

there is no `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` in the setting.py

###### url.py in app

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login' , LoginView.as_view()),
    path('user' , UserView.as_view())
]
```

###### main url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/' , include('users.urls'))
]
```

###### view.py

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    def post(self,request):
        
        username = request.data['username']
        password = request.data['password']
        
        user = User.objects.filter(username = username).first()
        
        if user is None:
            raise AuthenticationFailed("User not found")
        
        if not user.check_password(password):
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Incorrect Password')
        
        payload = {
            'id':  user.id,
            'exp':  datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
            'iat':  datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        }
        
        token = jwt.encode(payload , 'secret' , algorithm='HS256' )
        
        response = Response()
        
        response.set_cookie(key='jwt' , value=token , httponly=True)
        response.data = {
            'jwt': token
        }
        
        return response
```

###### settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

**for clarification**

###### this is the API url I used:

http://localhost:8000/api/login

###### when i use postman to call API I'm getting this error :

Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /api/login
[27/May/2023 18:53:53] "POST /api/login HTTP/1.1" 403 2870

###### when i use axios post I'm getting this error :

Forbidden (Origin checking failed - http://localhost:5173 does not match any trusted origins.): /api/login
[27/May/2023 18:58:15] "POST /api/login HTTP/1.1" 403 2569

I try to use csfr_exempt even though it's not a solution for this

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

urlpatterns = [
    path('login' , csrf_exempt(LoginView.as_view()))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `SessionAuthentication`? if yes, I think it is a cookie issue.

**Permanent Solution:** If you are using Postman, First, clear the existing cookies by clicking 'X' s. Then add correct cookie.

**Temporary Solution (for debugging):** Try this in your `settings.py`:

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
    # 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
]
```

Go [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme) for complete documentation